# Multidimensional array from form submit that i need to get the data and insert it into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have the following dump from a form that I'm working on and I need to insert the data into MySQL. My problem is that I'm a little confuse how should I handle the data from the form ( how to do the foreach or to find a better way to handle it).

Dump:

```
array(4) 
[
    "product_name_" => array(2) 
        [
            0 => string(10) "top hartie"
            2 => string(7) "pix gel"
        ]
    "quantity_"   => array(2) 
        [
            0 => string(1) "2"
            2 => string(1) "3"
        ]
    "price_"        => array(2) 
        [
            0 => string(3) "200"
            2 => string(2) "10"
        ]
    "Submit"       => string(6) "Submit"
]
```

Comment: **1)** Think about the SQL query (how it looks like) or just write it down **2)** Think about how to make that query using PHP **3)** Code it

Comment: INSERT INTO `invoice` (`productName`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES (:productName, :quantity, :price) xD

Comment: What i'm thinking of is using 3 foreach-uri to handle data from form.

Comment: You should build/name your form fields “the other way around”, so that you get an array with keys product_name, quantity etc. on _second_ level, and only a numerical index on the first – much easier to iterate over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll help to convert the array into a friendlier format:

```
$myData = array();
foreach($formData['product_name_'] as $key => $item){
    $myData[] = array('name' => $item, 
                      'quantity' => $formData['quantity_'][$key]
                      'price' => $formData['price'][$key]
                     );
}
```

You can then loop over `$myData` to do the inserts.

Note that this doesn't check that the array keys exist and it assumes that there will always be a quantity and price for each product name.